# Getting User ID Comment from a Post in RestFB

Tags: java, desktop-application, restfb

I need the user (or it's ID at least) who made a comment in a post.

It's a java desktop app.
I get the [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and selected all permissions, to test only.

I tried this way without success:

```
com.restfb.types.Page fetchedPage = facebookClient.fetchObject(pageName, com.restfb.types.Page.class);
//String pageID = fetchedPage.getId();
//String postID = "some post id from the 'fetchedPage'"
String postParam = "type,from,created_time,message,likes.summary(true),comments.order(chronological).summary(true){from{id}}";
com.restfb.types.Post fetchedPost = facebookClient.fetchObject(pageID + "_" + postID, com.restfb.types.Post.class, com.restfb.Parameter.with("fields", postParam));//the part 'from' of the 'comments' don't work as expected, returns null, that > "comments.order(chronological).summary(true){from{id}}"

com.restfb.types.Comments postComments = fetchedPost.getComments();
if(postComments != null){
    for(com.restfb.types.Comment comment : postComments.getData()){
        if(comment != null){
            //curiously I can not access the user who made the comment, but if it is a page that made a comment in the post it perfectly returns the user (which is a page)
            System.out.println("comment: " + comment.getFrom());// >> 'getFrom()' is null << that is what I need, the or at least the ID as told before.
            com.restfb.types.Comment fetchedComment = facebookClient.fetchObject(pageID + "_" + comment.getId(), com.restfb.types.Comment.class, com.restfb.Parameter.with("fields", "from,id,message,created_time,like_count,comment_count"));
            System.out.println("fetchedComment:  " + fetchedComment);//fetching like that the 'getFrom()' is null too...
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Any hint?
Sorry for the [bad English](https://translate.google.com.br/#pt/en/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the comment id, the user who made the comment and hers name, you can use this code.

```
String postId = pageID + "_" + postID; // you should not generate it, take it from the feed
Connection<Comment> commentConnection = facebookClient.fetchConnection(postId + "/comments", Comment.class,
  Parameter.with("fields", "id,from{name,id}"));

for (List<Comment> commentList : commentConnection) {
  for (Comment comment : commentList) {
    System.out.println("Comment ID: " + comment.getId());
    System.out.println("User ID: " + comment.getFrom().getId());
    System.out.println("User Name: " + comment.getFrom().getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get access token with:

1. Login to your facebook
2. Go to your profile page
3. Right click to "View Page Source"
4. Find text with key: "access_token"

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I need the USER that made the comment...
The example above get the comment and it's valid but without the user that made it, but the message itself is valid.